# Rails saving plain old string to SQlite as BLOB? I'm about to lose my mind!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have no idea why this would be happening, but Rails is saving a string to SQLite as a BLOB. Before creating a new user in my app I take their plain string password and MD5 it before saving to the database:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :encrypt_password

  def encrypt_password
    self.password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.password)
  end
end
```

But, the password field goes into SQLite as a freaking BLOB every time! The only way I could even tell is when exporting the table to SQL I can see the true nature of the field:

```
INSERT INTO "users" VALUES (24, 'john.doe@example.com', X'3639366432396530393430613439353737343866653366633965666432326133');
```

What the hell?? So now when I try to authenticate a user by looking up their email and MD5 hashed password it will fail every time. REAL strings don't match against BLOBs apparently:

```
User.find_by_email_and_password('john.doe@example.com', Digest::MD5.hexdigest('password') => nil
```

I have never used a BLOB in my entire life, let alone as the password field for a user table. My migrations clearly define `:string` as the datatype. Doing a `User.columns` clearly shows:

```
#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteColumn:0x00000105256ce0 @name="password", @sql_type="varchar(255)"
```

I've been working on this app for the better part of a month and have never seen this issue until last night when I was writing some tests for the User model. Testing trying to authenticate a user would fail every time, so I started manually building users in the console and come to find out the password would never match so all user lookups would fail.

The Rails debug info for creating a user looks like:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "first_name", "last_login_at", "last_name", "login_count", "password", "role_id", "twitter", "updated_at", "uuid") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 04 Jul 2011 18:50:58 UTC +00:00], ["email", "braulio_towne@runolfsson.name"], ["first_name", "Ebba"], ["last_login_at", nil], ["last_name", "Bayer"], ["login_count", nil], ["password", "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99"], ["role_id", 2], ["twitter", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 04 Jul 2011 18:50:58 UTC +00:00], ["uuid", "7ab57110-889c-012e-e207-482a140835c4"]]
```

Which, when I convert to regular SQL works just fine, so there's gotta be something else going on somewhere. What is going on?!?!

- sqlite3 3.6.12
- rails 3.1.0.rc4
- sqlite3-ruby 1.3.3

### UPDATE

It gets stranger and stranger...if I hardcode some random string in my `encrypt_password` method then it goes into the database correctly:

```
def encrypt_password
  self.password = 'foo'
end
```

I can even hardcode it to the actual MD5 hash of the string 'password' and it works:

```
def encrypt_password
  self.password = '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99'
end
```

But if I tell it to `Digest::MD5.hexdigest('password')` then it goes in as a BLOB.

Now, if I add *anything* onto the string created by the digest, then it works!

```
def encrypt_password
  self.password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.password) + ' '
end
```

What the hell is that?? So for now my workout is to add a newline and then chomp it off:

```
def encrypt_password
  self.password = (Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.password) + "\n").chomp
end
```

I feel like I should open a ticket in Rails somewhere, but this is so amazingly strange that I don't want to get laughed out of the community forever for even suggesting that something like this could be happening!

Comment: Could you log `Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.password).class` and check the output? It's strange that adding a space works. What about setting password to `Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.password).to_s`?

Comment: I tried that, everything went through as a String. Turns out it was an encoding issue, see answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out this was an encoding issue. See the ticket here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1965

`hexdigest` returns an ASCII string, but when you go back to query against that same field the query runs as a UTF-8 string. I assume that as soon as I manually added something to the string it was converted to UTF-8 behind the scenes and then was properly saved to the DB as UTF-8. Here's the fix:

```
def encrypt_password
  self.password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.password).encode('UTF-8')
end
```

Comment: I just ran into this exact problem in some Ruby/SQLite code that had nothing to do with Rails. You saved me I-don't-know-how-many-hours of head scratching. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Straight up MD5 hashing isn't great for security. Someone breaks an email/password database elsewhere using this method and they can hack into your site with ease.

Consider using Bcrypt. The following taken from http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org:

```
require 'bcrypt'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # users.password_hash in the database is a :string
  include BCrypt

  def password
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)
    @password = Password.create(new_password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end

end
```

Add a migration to rename 'password' as 'password_hash'.

This should also have the knock on effect of solving the serialization problem you are having with the result of the hexdigest method.

Comment: How does this work? Each time I run Password.create(new_password) I get a different hash...how would I ever authenticate the user's plain text password when they try to log in? I can't compare against the hash in the database because it won't match any more. I expected something like this method in Railscasts where you re-hash the user's plain text password on login and compare against the hash in the database: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Comment: you just do user.find_by_email(params[:email]).password == params[:password]. It overrides the equality operator for you. The reason is that it is a different hash each time is that the algorithm securely generates completely unique hashes each time you use the method, thus eradicating the possibility of using a rainbow table to crack the password.