# Sqlite where clause is not working (is this a bug?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I was debugging a Ruby on Rails engine which has problems when running on Sqlite, it has a problem in finding records that the app itself creates. When run on MySQL everything works but the same query on SQLite is failing.

I've tracked down the issue and I found that the problem is in a simple WHERE query which won't find the created record. Essentially the table structure has a column called key which stores some md5 hashes. The failing spec insert a record with a given hash then on the following instruction do a SELECT query for the same hash, but SQLite returns no record for the same key. I've extracted the generated database and the failing query from the app and this is a copy of the app database:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2289657/combustion_test.sqlite

Here is a transcript of the queries executed by the software (made with the command line utility):

```
# Here I'm selecting all the records from the table
# there is a single record  in it, the key is the third field
$ sqlite3 combustion_test.sqlite 'SELECT * FROM tr8n_translation_keys'
1||b56c67d10759f8012aff28fc03f26cbf|Hello World|We must start with this sentence!||||en-US|0|2012-03-14 11:49:50.335322|2012-03-14 11:49:50.335322|

# Here I'm selecting the record with that key and it doesn't return anything
$ sqlite3 combustion_test.sqlite "SELECT * FROM tr8n_translation_keys WHERE key = 'b56c67d10759f8012aff28fc03f26cbf'"

# Here I'selecting the record with a LIKE clause and it finds the record
$ sqlite3 combustion_test.sqlite "SELECT * FROM tr8n_translation_keys WHERE key LIKE 'b56c67d10759f8012aff28fc03f26cbf'"
1||b56c67d10759f8012aff28fc03f26cbf|Hello World|We must start with this sentence!||||en-US|0|2012-03-14 11:49:50.335322|2012-03-14 11:49:50.335322|
```

Should I report this as a bug to SQLite site?

P.S. I've tried also on a different system with a different SQLite version, but the results are the same.

### Update

Here is the table schema

```
sqlite> .schema tr8n_translation_keys
CREATE TABLE "tr8n_translation_keys" (
   "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
   "type" varchar(255), "key" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   "label" text NOT NULL, 
   "description" text, 
   "verified_at" datetime, 
   "translation_count" integer, 
   "admin" boolean, 
   "locale" varchar(255), 
   "level" integer DEFAULT 0, 
   "created_at" datetime, 
   "updated_at" datetime, 
   "synced_at" datetime
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_tr8n_translation_keys_on_key" ON "tr8n_translation_keys" ("key");
CREATE INDEX "index_tr8n_translation_keys_on_synced_at" ON "tr8n_translation_keys" ("synced_at");
```

### Update 2

Here is the rails code which compute the key value inserted into the table (I've removed some code, full method [is here](https://github.com/berk/tr8n/blob/master/app/models/tr8n/translation_key.rb#L44))

```
def self.find_or_create(label, desc = "", options = {})
  key = generate_key(label, desc).to_s
  # IF I UNCOMMENT THIS LINE EVERYTHING WORKS
  #key = 'b56c67d10759f8012aff28fc03f26cbf'
  
  tkey = Tr8n::Cache.fetch("translation_key_#{key}") do
    existing_key = where(:key => key).first ### THIS IS THE FAILING WHERE
    
    existing_key ||= begin
      new_tkey = create(:key => key.to_s, 
                        :label => label, 
                        :description => desc, 
                        :locale => locale,
                        :level => level,
                        :admin => Tr8n::Config.block_options[:admin])
# rest of method...
```

And here is the generate_key method, the comment about sqlite is from author, not mine)

```
def self.generate_key(label, desc = "")
  # TODO: there is something iffy going on with the strings from the hash
  # without the extra ~ = the strings are not seen in the sqlite database - wtf?
  "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{label};;;#{desc}")}"
end
```

Comment: Please post your table definition also.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I've posted the table schema

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM tr8n_translation_keys WHERE LOWER(key)='b56c67d10759f8012aff28fc03f26cbf';
```

But this doesn't:

```
SELECT * FROM tr8n_translation_keys WHERE key='b56c67d10759f8012aff28fc03f26cbf' COLLATE NOCASE;
```

When I examine the database in SQLiteManager, it shows the `key` as this:

```
X'6235366336376431303735396638303132616666323866633033663236636266'
```

which implies it's treating the `key` as a `BLOB` (raw binary data) rather than `TEXT`. This is why the comparison fails. But `LOWER(key)` causes the field to be cast to text, hence the comparison succeeds.

So, we need to find out why the entry has been stored as a `BLOB` instead of `TEXT`. How were these values inserted into the database?

---

Following your **update 2**: I'm not a Ruby expert, but the value returned from `generate_key` is not being converted to a string in the way you expect. Try `to_str` instead of `to_s` when calling `generate_key`.

Comment: So the problem should be in something related to case sensitivity related? This would explain why the LIKE selection is working. Is there a way to see raw data stored in the field? Just to see what is actually stored in that record.

Comment: That's pretty strange, the table was created by a rails migration, this is the first time I see an issue like this one. I've managed a lot of tables with RoR migrations and they never did something strange. I think I'll post a bug report to SQLite site. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following Stack Overflow answer...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591427/18064

... you might want to update the generation of your key as follows:

```
def self.generate_key(label, desc = "")
   # TODO: there is something iffy going on with the strings from the hash
   # without the extra ~ = the strings are not seen in the sqlite database - wtf?
   "#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{label};;;#{desc}").encode('UTF-8')}"
end
```

Note the addition of `.encode('UTF-8')`.

This worked for me when I had the same problem as yourself.